# Why does this Int Value keep coming back after it is set? [Roblox Studio]

Tags: lua, roblox

I'm sorry if this is a really simple or easy question, but I am trying to set the player leaderstat "Money" to 0, but it keeps coming back as the old value. The only thing that I can think of that may be causing this problem is that the moneyGain script is on repeat.

**Here is my moneyGain script:**

```
local playerMoney

while wait(0.24) do
    local buttons = script.Parent.Parent.info.savedItems.Value.buttons:GetChildren()
    for button = 1, #buttons, 1 do
        if buttons[button].Parent.Parent.tycoon.Value ~= nil then
            if buttons[button].Parent.Parent.tycoon.Value.info.owner ~= nil then
                if buttons[button].jobDone.Value == true then
                    script.Parent.moneyEnforcer.enforce:Invoke(buttons[button].gainVal.Value)
                end
            end
        end
    end
    
    --OWNERDOOR:
    if script.Parent.Parent.info.owner.Value ~= nil then
        script.Parent.moneyEnforcer.enforce:Invoke(1)
    end
end
```

**Here is my moneyEnforcer script:**

```
local rs = game:GetService("ReplicatedStorage")
local dictionary = require(rs.dictionary)
local vipPlayers = dictionary.vipPlayers

script.enforce.OnInvoke = function(amount)
    print(amount)
    if script.Parent.Parent.info.player.Value ~= nil then
        if game:GetService("GamePassService"):PlayerHasPass(script.Parent.Parent.info.player.Value, 25494219) then
            amount = amount * 2
        else
            for i = 1, #vipPlayers, 1 do
                if script.Parent.Parent.info.player.Value.Name == vipPlayers[i] then
                    amount = amount * 2
                end
            end
        end
        local playerMoney = script.Parent.Parent.info.player.Value.leaderstats.Money
        script.Parent.Parent.info.player.Value.leaderstats.Money.Value = script.Parent.Parent.info.player.Value.leaderstats.Money.Value + amount
    end
end
```

**And here is the tycoon reseter:**

```
local player = script.Parent.Parent.Parent.Parent.Parent.Parent
script.Parent.Parent.Parent.Visible = false

script.Parent.MouseButton1Click:Connect(function()
    player.leaderstats.Money.Value = 0
    script.Parent.Parent.Parent.Visible = false
    local savedItems = player.claimedTycoon.Value.info.savedItems.Value
    local builds = player.claimedTycoon.Value.activeBuilds:GetChildren()
    local buttons = player.claimedTycoon.Value.activeButtons:GetChildren()
    for i = 1, #builds, 1 do
        builds[i].Parent = savedItems.builds
    end
    for j = 1, #buttons, 1 do
        buttons[j].Parent = savedItems.buttons
    end
    savedItems.builds.dirtStarterBase.Parent = player.claimedTycoon.Value
    player.claimedTycoon.Value.info:WaitForChild("activeWave").Value = 1
end)
```

I have tried putting the "script.Parent.Parent.info.player.Value.leaderstats.Money.Value = script.Parent.Parent.info.player.Value.leaderstats.Money.Value + amount" on the moneyGain script, but that made no difference.

Any help is appriciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe your problem is that you're setting the value of money **from the client.** When you change the value from a local script, it will not update on the server. To fix this **update the value from the server**

In **tycoon reseter**, try resetting the value from the server using a [RemoteEvent](https://developer.roblox.com/en-us/api-reference/class/RemoteEvent#remoteevents-client-to-server)